# ReplayKit returns error "RPRecordingErrorFailedToStart"

Tags: c++, frameworks, ios9, objective-c++

I am trying to include recording functionality to my C++ based game with `ReplayKit`. I check that the iOS version is 9.0 or above in my game code, and if it is, I will call `RecordReplayIOS::startRecording()` and then the ReplayKit should start recording.

For some reason the `startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled` function returns always an error `-5803`, which according to API documentation means `RPRecordingErrorFailedToStart`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

`RecordReplayIOS.hpp`:

```
#ifndef __RECORD_REPLAY_IOS_HPP__
#define __RECORD_REPLAY_IOS_HPP__

class RecordReplayIOS {
public:
    static bool canRecord();
    static void startRecording();
    static void stopRecording();
};

#endif
```

`RecordReplayIOS.mm`:

```
#include "RecordReplay_ios.hpp"
#include "ReplayKit/ReplayKit.h"

@interface Recorder : NSObject
+(void)startRecording;
+(void)stopRecording;
@end

#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)

bool RecordReplayIOS::canRecord() {
    // ReplayKit needs at least iOS 9
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"9.0")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void RecordReplayIOS::startRecording() {
    [Recorder startRecording];
}

void RecordReplayIOS::stopRecording() {
    [Recorder stopRecording];
}

@implementation Recorder

+(void)startRecording {
    RPScreenRecorder* recorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder;
    recorder.delegate = self;
    [recorder startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled:false handler:^(NSError * error) {
        if(error != nil) {
            NSString* desc = error.description;
            return;
        }
    }];
}

+(void)stopRecording {
    RPScreenRecorder* recorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder;
    [recorder stopRecordingWithHandler:^(RPPreviewViewController *previewViewController, NSError *error) {
        if(error != nil) {
            NSString* desc = error.description;
            return;
        }
        if(previewViewController) {
            //do stuff...    
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. It seems that I just tried to use ReplayKit with an iPad which was too old. Apparently ReplayKit needs either A7 or A8 processor. My iPad 4 which has A6 processor simply does not work with ReplayKit.

The correct way to check if the device can use ReplayKit is to query `RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder.available`. It returns true if the device supports ReplayKit.

Comment: Yeah, not supported on an iPhone 5c either.