# Replaykit generate log "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.ReplayKit.RPRecordingErrorDomain error -5803.)" on start recording

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

```
 func startRecording() {
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
    recorder.startRecording(withMicrophoneEnabled: false, handler: { (error) in
        if let unwrappedError = error {
            print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.videoRecButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.stopRecording), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    })

}

func stopRecording() {
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
    recorder.stopRecording { [unowned self] (preview, error) in self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =    UIBarButtonItem(title: "Start", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.startRecording))
        if let unwrappedPreview = preview {
            unwrappedPreview.previewControllerDelegate = self
            self.present(unwrappedPreview, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

On recorder.startRecording() and recorder.stopRecording()... it generates error as "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.ReplayKit.RPRecordingErrorDomain error -5803.)"

also I'm not getting permission popup.

Comment: it is ipad 9.3.2.

Comment: iPad 2 ...I got issue it's not supported for this device...reason - don't know but I check with "isAvailable".

Comment: Yes its not supported

Answer (score 2):

The error code [-5803](https://developer.apple.com/reference/replaykit/rprecordingerrorcode/1620117-failedtostart) means `RPRecordingErrorFailedToStart` (all error codes can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/replaykit/rprecordingerrorcode))

This post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33627512/4063602

mentions that:

> Apparently ReplayKit needs either A7 or A8 processor

To see if you are able to use ReplayKit on a device, you can use the property `isAvailable` on `RPScreenRecorder`. As it says in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder/1620992-isavailable):

> When set to true, the screen recorder is available for recording. Screen recording can be unavailable due to unsupported hardware, the user’s device displaying information over Airplay or through a TVOut session, or another app using the recorder.

Hope this helps.